# Correctly configuring SSL on TULEAP

Tags: ssl, tuleap

There is very little information and it does not reflect situation can anyone properly explain how to put [tuleap](https://tuleap.net/) on ssl?

Comment: Is this programming related question?

Answer (score 3):

For tuleap side, everything is done in `/etc/codendi/conf/local.inc` (or `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc`, depending on your system). All you have to do is check that `$sys_https_host` is correctly set and eventually set `$sys_force_ssl` to 1.

For it to work properly, your server must have a valid SSL certificate. I personnaly recommend [StartSSL.com](http://www.startssl.com) as they are free and simple, but it's all personnal choice. You can read how to install certificate for CentOS [here](http://bin63.com/how-to-secure-apache-with-a-free-ssl-certificate-from-startssl-on-centos) (skip the vhost part) and for debian [there](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps).

Answer (score 1):

Since Tuleap uses nginx, the easiest way is using `sudo certbot --nginx` for Ubuntu Xenial https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx